# Adding a field to django built in signup form

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am trying to create a custom sign up form in my django project but I still want to use `from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm` that already has some built in fields. I have already created a form that adds the field but I don't know how to add this to model

```
from django import forms 
from django.contrib.auth.forms. import UserCreation
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.CharField(max_length=254, required=True, widget=forms.EmailInput())
    teamNumber = forms.CharField(max_length=4, required=True)

    class Meta:
        Model = User
        fields= ('username', 'email', 'teamNumber', 'password1', 'password2')
```

I have tried using the abstractUser but that led to a mixture of errors.

Comment: please read the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using **one-to-one linking** method, what you have to do is create new model (say '**Profile**') with additional fields and link this model to built-in user model as one-to-one.

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    #one-to-one link with built-in model
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    #additional fields
    email = forms.CharField(max_length=254, required=True, widget=forms.EmailInput())
    teamNumber = forms.CharField(max_length=4, required=True)
```

This links the two models, but still you have to define two signals (in the same model.py file) to get the model working,

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

These signals create and save profile entries on create and update of built-in user model.

Also you need not create your own email field as built-in User model already has a email field, make sure you check it out :)

**Note:** There are other methods of achieving this but I personally prefer this method over other two (mentioned on below link) as it is much cleaner and simpler to maintain and think about.

**Do check out this awesome blog about extending Django's built-in user model:** [link](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html)
The author there has beautifully explained all the three methods and how they work.